# Defining Proper Classes with Java

Tags: java

Ok, I'm studying Java and have the following question: 
"Assume you defined a class named MyClass. A student wants to use your class and tries to declare an instance named myObj and instantiate it. He tried the following:

```
MyObj MyClass = new MyClass( );
```

Why won't his code work? Show how he should correct it. "

I'm not sure how to do this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I did.  I'm still not sure

Comment: The name of the class is MyClass not MyObj. It should be something like MyClass myObj = new MyClass(); .

Comment: The textbook wants to confuse you by not adhering to Java naming conventions. : ) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: First you have to study on how to create an Object @user2579706

Comment: Thank you al for your help.  It was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyClass and MyObj are the wrong way around, it should be:

```
MyClass MyObj = new MyClass();
```

Otherwise you are trying to declare an instance of MyObj which doesn't exist. Instead you declare an instance of MyClass and name this MyObj. Hopefully that makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here MyObj is object not classtype. try this out.

```
MyClass MyObj = new MyClass( );
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
MyClass MyObj = new MyClass( );
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the class is MyClass. The name of the instance is myObj.

It should be:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass(); // One instance
MyClass myObj2 = new MyClass(); // Another instance of the class.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct way to create an object :

```
ClassName instanceName = new ClassName();
```

As the question said: "Assume you defined a class named `MyClass`. A student wants to use your class and tries to declare an instance named `myObj` and instantiate it"

From the question, we can see that `MyClass` is a class name and `myObj` is an instance name.

So to create an object for the above question, try:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
```

Btw `MyClass()` is a constructor. Please go through basic Object and classes chapters.